# How can new users get started to Super User?

Tags: support, asking-questions

I've just posted a question which is put on hold and then deleted. After sometime I realized from notice and comments that I may have posted unsuitable question to the site. So, I think I need to be familiar with this site and users who run or participate this site.

So, I want to ask "How new users can get started to this site?"

p.s. please don't delete this question because I think this can really help (useful to) new users.

Hope for favourable response.

Comment: At the top, there's a button that says help. Click it, then look for "Help Center". It will tell you the do's and dont's.

Comment: Ok. I'll take a look. By the way, do I have to complete sign up in order to get full access to the site?

Comment: Oh! which different website I'm seeing this? It shows meta label. I'm looking bit confused!

Comment: Meta is where we ask questions *about* the site rather than questions *for* the site. I migrated your question here as this is where this particular type of question should be. It is preferable for you to fully register an account, otherwise you might loose access to it if you clear cookies in your browser or move to a new computer.

Comment: I've always felt a little time lurking always does one good. Its useful to get an idea of the scope and context of *any* site before actually engaging in it. You're in a odd situation if you've heard of Jeff Atwood (and asked questions about him... in the wrong place) and have no idea what the *third oldest site on the network is about*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can start by [taking the tour](https://superuser.com/tour). It will show you how things work here.

Then you should read the [help centre](https://superuser.com/help). Specifically the following pages should be looked at:

- [What topics can I ask here?](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic)
- [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask)
- [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask)
- [How do I write a good answer?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer)